# How to reverse XOR-shift operations

Tags: c, xor, shift

I have the following xor-shift encoder

```
char a[] = "text";
int b = strlen(a);
for (int c = 0; c < b; c++) {
    if (c > 0) a[c] ^= a[c-1];
    a[c] ^= a[c] >> 3;
    a[c] ^= a[c] >> 2;
    a[c] ^= a[c] >> 1;
    printf("%02x", (unsigned int)(a[c]));
}
```

I'd like to revert the hex output to the original string.

Is it even possible, considering that the shift would in some cases eliminate bits on the right side that can't be retrieved anymore? And if it is possible, how could the operations be reverted?

Comment: Whopping 256 possible values. Build a lookup table.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I replied with similar idea before, but it looks like every element is depending on the previous one

Comment: @EugeneSh. *This* dependency is easily reversible.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Indeed. So proving/disproving reversibility (by table) for `a[1]` should be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not that hard. Just map the xor-shit results back to their original values. Consider this function:

```c
char f(char c) {
    c ^= c >> 3;
    c ^= c >> 2;
    c ^= c >> 1;
    return c;
}
```

You should be able to satisfy yourself that for every possible input value (from 0 to 127), there is a corresponding unique output. (Of course, if you change `char` to `unsigned char`, then the function will work on any 8-bit input.)

With this function, you can easily create an array to perform the reverse of this function:

```c
char g(char c) {
    static char *map = NULL;
    if (!map) {
        map = malloc(128);
        for (int i=0; i<128; i++) map[f(i)] = i;
    }
    return map[c];
}
```

Then just write a function to read each character of a string in turn, apply this reverse function, and then XOR the result with the previous value:

```c
char *decode(char *s, int len) {
    char *start = s, last = 0;
    while (len--) {
        char tmp = *s;
        *s = last ^ g(*s);
        last = tmp;
        s++;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A lookup table would work in this situation with only 8-bit values, but it is also possible to do this reversal without one.

To reverse `x ^= x >> a` do:

```
x ^= x >> a;
x ^= x >> (2*a);
x ^= x >> (4*a);
x ^= x >> (8*a);
// ...
```

Until the shift amount `a` exceeds the bit width of the type. With that in mind you could have encoding and decoding functions like so:

```
void encode(unsigned char* str, size_t len) {
    for (int c = 0; c < len; c++) {
        if (c > 0) str[c] ^= str[c-1];
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 3;
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 2;
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 1;
    }
}

void decode(unsigned char* str, size_t len) {
    for (int c = len - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 1;
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 2;
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 4;
        
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 2;
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 4;
        
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 3;
        str[c] ^= str[c] >> 6;
        if (c > 0) str[c] ^= str[c-1];
    }
}
```